# table row with visible shadow

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to achieve this:

set up a table with rows that have space between each others in order to show their box-shadow

I managed to set it up with display:block.
How ever I couldnt find out how to expand the containing td Elements with percentages in order to be able to use a responsive design

here is the fiddle and the code that should show you what i mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/dN5DM/247/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label A </td>
        <td>longLabel B</td>
        <td>short</td>
    </tr>
</table>


table{
    width : 100%;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 5px;  /* how? margin on both sides visible */
}
tr {
    display: block; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
td {
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 33%;  /* how? expanding the tds to fill the whole row? */
}
```

​

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Use `div`'s and style those instead.  Also, please make your question fully self-contained.  Nothing wrong with a supplemental jsFiddle to show a demo, but if that's all you have, then the question becomes useless when the link goes dead.

Comment: Finally, you do not include your `<head>` section or `<html></html>` tags in a jsFiddle.  Only the _contents_ of your `<body></body>` go inside the "HTML" section.  Anything else is superfluous and likely ignored.  See http://jsfiddle.net/dN5DM/246/

Comment: Edited code to the question. I can't use divs since I am using a larger framework from my company. Do you mean by "use divs instead" that there is no possible way to get this done within a table?

Comment: It's probably possible with `table`'s.  You'll just be more semantically correct with `div`'s and browsers will likely have an easier time too.  What kind of framework won't allow `div`'s, the most basic of HTML elements?

Comment: I've been playing around with this and see what you mean.  It seems like `display: block` as well as `float` are breaking this.  I think it's because it's taking the children out of the flow.  However, since they're part of a `table`, taking them out of their normal flow causes the % `width` to be ignored since that's with respect to its parent.

Comment: thank you for trying. and no the framework isnt forbidding divs. but when you use predefined layouts to place some controlls (or views or how ever they are called in other frameworks) (i.e. sproutcore) you have to style code, that is build from your javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so got it working but not as nearly as you want(say 95%..:)). This is the closest I could get.

Since, you used display:block on the table-row, its no more behaving as a table-row but as a block element, that's why your cells are not taking up the 33%(Reason, I don't know, maybe someone knows). But then if you need to apply style(shadow) to rows you needed to do this.

I tried to change the table cells to display:block. The table cells did take up the full-space but now the table-rows showed no shadows(Why???, I think because they are now behaving as table-rows, back again.). So, finally thinking about nothing more, I applied shadows to the table cells and removed all display:block everywhere). Eureka, shadows did show, the only thing is that shadows are now on the cells instead of the rows and visually it may not be the result you are wanting 100%. Anyway, here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dN5DM/267/).